# How to expect httpReq.request.headers.get('authorization').toBeTruthy()?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6, angular-services, angular-http-interceptors

I am having a problem to get the unit testing of interceptor done because it tells me that httpReq.request.headers.get('authorization').toBeTruthy() must be tobefalsy().even i am giving the token to it and then attaching that token with the authorization Token Header as shown in the following code but this gives me error. This is interceptor service code:

`

```
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private auth: CoreService) {
    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (this.auth.getToken()) {
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    authorization: `Token ${this.auth.getToken()}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

`

i have tried different approaches to make this correct and even i have debugged this code token is coming but when we expect this to be truthy this tells me that token is null

this is code of spec file

`

```
 it('should add a Authorization token to the authorization header', () => {
        coreService.setToken('this is my dummy token');
        const token = coreService.getToken();
        const spy = coreSpy.getToken();
        const someData = { data: 'someData ' };
        http.get('localhost:3000/anonymous/user').subscribe((data) => {
            expect(data).toEqual(someData);
        });
        const httpReq = httpTestingController.expectOne('localhost:3000/anonymous/user');
        expect(httpReq.request.method).toBe('GET');
        expect(httpReq.request.headers.get('authorization')).toBeTruthy();
        expect(httpReq.request.headers.get('authorization')).toBe(`Token ${token}`);
        httpReq.flush(someData);
        httpTestingController.verify();
    });
```

`

expected result is that it must tell me that this is true that we get authorization.

Comment: What does your spied `getToken` return? Because the header is only set if it's truthy.

Comment: getToken() returns the token of this my dummy token.

Comment: getToken() is giving the result but its not being attached with the headers

Comment: setToken(token: string) {
        localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, token);
    }

Comment: getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem(this.storageKey);
    }

Comment: these are the functions

Comment: You're using the *real* collaborator? Why is it named spy? How is it configured? Is it getting called? I'd suggest mocking it out and giving a [mcve] showing the test setup.

Comment: [Edit] the question!

Answer (score -1):

I think we ran into the same issue and in the end we decided to only unit test the request and verify, that req.clone is called with the right params using a spy rather than testing, that clone uses the param to alter the request accordingly.

Comment: Erbsenkoenig can you share the code? How did you do that?

Comment: This is a test of *implementation*, not *behaviour*.